# Unable to reach my pictures from my css after moving css files into new css folder

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

Before updating my css, I had the following in Login.css:

```
body
{    
  background-image: url('./pictures/fond.png');    
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Here was my structure:

[image]

Now I have the following css:

```
body
{    
  background-image: url('../pictures/fond.png');    
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Please note the double point in the url.

Here is my new structure:

[image]

**My problem**: when publishing on my IIS test server, I cannot see my pictures!? On local dev machine (VS2012) I can see my pictures.

BUT If I update my Login.css located in my IIS test server and replace my double points with a single point it works again. It is not logic because (after my update) the Login.css is now located under the css folder.

Any idea?

Thanks.

UPDATE ----------------

Here is the way I refererence my css:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bundleLogin").Include(
            "~/Content/css/bootstrap.css",
            "~/Content/css/Login.css"));
```

I created a bundle and then:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/bundleLogin")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet you have hardcoded the path to your CSS file in the view, like that:

```
<link href="Content/css/Login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

instead of doing it the correct waywhich of course is to use an url helper:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/Login.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

As far as your CSS file is concerned, all urls that you are referencing there (such as images) are always relative to the current location of the CSS file. So if you properly reference your CSS file you will not have any problems. Using `url('../pictures/fond.png');` is the correct relative location.

---

UPDATE:

Oh, I see the problem. You are using bundles. Well, the problem with bundles is that the way you declared the name of your bundle, you do not have the same level of folder nesting as the physical structure. So modify your bundle like this:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css/bundleLogin").Include(
        "~/Content/css/bootstrap.css",
        "~/Content/css/Login.css"));
```

and then:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css/bundleLogin")
```

Comment: Please see my update in my question to understand how I reference my css from my view. Thanks.

Comment: Oh now I see. You are using bundles. That's the problem. Lemme update my answer.